# Changing the package name in all the java files to the existing package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created some package. I had java files from previously created package. Now, I want to change the name of package inside all java files to the package i just created in eclipse. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Right Click > Refactor > Move

Answer (score 0):

right click package name in **package explorer** then ---> refactor ---->rename

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the two folders where the projects are contained
2. Move the .java files inside the /src/*your package name* folder of your old project to the /src/*your new package name* folder in your new project
3. Fix the errors popping out by eclipse: Change the old package name in your .java files to the new package name.

Answer (score 0):

Select the package in either the **Package Explorer** or the **Project Explorer** when inside the **Java** Perspective, then use the menu bar or context menu to **Refactor**->**Rename**, or press the shortcut:

```
Alt+Shift+R
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your package then choose refactor and select rename.

Answer (score 0):

Select package and press `F2`.
In new wizard enter new package name and click on `OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the package and press Alt+Shift+R gives you option for rename and rename it. it will change in all the java files.